# How to realloc() in the middle of an array?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have an array of pointers

```
    char *wordlist[9];
```

and then I malloc() a block of memory on every of this pointers

```
for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    wordList[i] = (char*)malloc(someLength);
```

Lets suppose that every time the someLength is different.

And the problem is now, that I want to realloc() ie. 4th elemet of wordList to a larger size than it is now.

```
wordList[3] = (char*) realloc(&wordList[3], someBiggerSize);
```

Since malloc allocates a consistent block of memory, is that operation even possible without colliding with wordList[4]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to worry about this in principle. You just have an array of pointers and each element of the array points to a distinct memory block. Each element of the array, each pointer, can be therefore be reallocated independent of the other elements.

Now, I say in principle because your code does have an error. You should pass `wordList[3]` rather than `&wordList[3]` to the `realloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it be colliding? You have declared an array of pointers, each of which points to memory that is allocated elsewhere. When you reallocate you are just changing the size/position of this memory, the pointer returned by `realloc` is as big as it was.

By the way, you shouldn't be using `realloc` that way, since, if it fails, you'd be leaking memory; see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986538/how-to-handle-realloc-when-it-fails-due-to-memory).

---edit---

And, as @asaelr noted, you should remove that `&`, just `realloc`ing the block pointed by `wordList[3]`, not the memory of `wordList`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `&` . `wordList[3] = (char*) realloc(wordList[3], someBiggerSize);`

`wordList[3]` is a pointer, and realloc expected to get a pointer that allocated by `malloc`. not pointer to it.

About your last question: every time you call `malloc`, it return a consistent block of memory. there is not guarantee that memory, allocated by two calls for `malloc`, will be consistent. In other words, `wordList[3]` and `wordList[4]` are not must be consistent, and you can do whatever you want two one of them (as long as you care about the buffers size) without thinking about the other.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your pointers points to a separate and independent block of memory. Inside your array of pointers, each element is simply an address and overwriting one won't affect the others. So, what you are doing is fine and won't cause any problems with other elements of the array. As others mentioned, you should be passing `wordList[3]` and not `&wordList[3]`

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding about what `realloc` does. It will return a whole new block of memory (if the new size is larger than the old size) instead of increasing the size of the block that was passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

malloc allocates a trunk of memory from heap and that trunk of memory can't be allocated for other malloc until you free them. In other words, malloc succeeds only if there are enough continuous free space in the heap. So this makes sure that the memory allocated would not collide with any others in your words.