# Dynamically allocate memory for array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I allocated memory to an array (using `malloc`) but what if it needs more space, is it possible to expand the array later in the program? Or maybe create a new array and have the last element in the first array point to the new array?
**I know that `realloc` would be much easier to use but I am trying to do this only using `malloc`.**

Comment: To change the size look at realloc

Comment: I am trying to do this without using realloc only malloc

Comment: Take a look at the man page for memcpy, instead of copying elements in the for loop.  But yes, this is the right idea.

Comment: I'm confused about the line `newArray=new array(array1)`
You're using malloc, so I'm not sure what that is meant to be

Comment: Also, don't cast the void pointer returned from malloc.  If you absolutely must, then make sure that you `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: I wasn't sure how to implement what Dwayne explained. The  current array = newly created array (the one you copied into)

Comment: You need to check whether `num` is out of range *before* you write to `array1[num]`, not afterwards. In your current code you'll write to `array1[100]` before you figure out that that's past the end of your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general algorithm is

```
allocate array of 100
while more input
    if no-room-in-array
        allocate another array 100 bigger than the current array
        copy values from current array into newly created array
        free(current array)
        current array = newly created array (the one you copied into)
    // now there will be room, so
    put input in array
```

Comment: Don't change your question. If you need to add something add it.

Comment: No it doesn't, my implementation of current array = newly created array (the one you copied into) is wrong. Not really sure why

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `realloc()`.  Be careful to check the return value *before* you assign it to the original pointer though.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986572/4323

Comment: Like I said I cant use realloc

Comment: @user2737810: what platform are you on that you can't use realloc()?

Comment: The program specs dont allow realloc

Answer (score 1):

Wrong size passed to `malloc()`.

Rather than passing `n` bytes, code should pass `n * sizeof(int)`.

```
// int *array1=(int *)malloc(100);
int *array1 = malloc(100 * sizeof *array1);

// int *newArray=(int *)malloc(size+100);
int *newArray =  malloc((size+100) * szeof *newArray);
```

Other ideas include

1) No need to cast

```
    int *array1 = (int *) malloc(...;
    int *array1 = malloc(...);
```

2) Simplify with `memcpy()`

```
    // for(i=0; i<size; i++) newArray[i]=array1[i];
    memcpy(newArray, array, size * sizeof *newArray);
```

3) Be sure to `free()`

4) `new` is a C++ operator, this is C, use `malloc()`.

5) Use `size_t` rather than `int` for `size`.

6) Grow exponentially, rather than linearly

```
// int *newArray=(int *)malloc(size+100);
size_t newsize = size*3/2;
int *newArray = malloc(newsize);
```

7) Check for `malloc()` failure

```
int *newArray = malloc(newsize);
if (newArray == NULL && newsize > 0) Handle_Failure();
```