# allocating memory as the program runs

Tags: c, loops, memory, malloc

Hi there I am trying to write a program that will create memory during run time, such that the program could run continuously as it generates memory to store strings until the user decides to quit. However, when I run the program I can enter the strings properly, however printing them out is another story. I believe the issue is that in the loop I am overwriting the memory that was created through each iteration. Here is what I have thus far:

```
int main(){
    char **lines = NULL;
    char sentence[1000];
    int numOfLines = 1;
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Enter the sentence:\n");
    lines = (lines, numOfLines * sizeof *lines); 

    for (i=0; i <= numOfLines; i++){

        fgets(sentence, 1000, stdin);
        lines[i] = malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(sentence) +1);
        if (strcmp(sentence, ".\n") == 0){ //exits loops if entered string is "."
              break;
        }
        strcpy(lines[i], sentence); 
        numOfLines++;
        printf("%s", lines[i]); // attempt at a Debug statement
    }
   numOfLines = numOfLines - 1;

   for (j = numOfLines; j>=0; j--){ //prints out the lines in reverse
       printf("%s\n", lines[j]);
   }
   return 0;

}
```

I might add that I get a segmentation fault when the user exits the loop.

Comment: I'd expect `lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * numOfLines);` to be before the `for()` loop.

Comment: Tip: when using debug statements like `printf("%s", lines[i]);`, add sentinels to show leading/trailing whitespace.  `printf("<%s>\n", lines[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues

You do this on each loop

```
lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * numOfLines);
```

If you exit early lines not used are full of random gunk

Try (Note: FIX the NYI's)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char sentence[1000]; // NYI - fix magic
    int numOfLines = 0;
    int maxNumOfLines = 10;
    char **lines=malloc(sizeof(char *) * maxNumOfLines); // NYI - calloc

    bzero(lines, sizeof(char *) * maxNumOfLines); // NYI - calloc

    printf("Enter the sentence:\n");

    for (int i=0; i < maxNumOfLines; i++) { 
      fgets(sentence, 1000, stdin);
      lines[i] = malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(sentence) + 1);

      if (strcmp(sentence, ".\n") == 0){
        strcpy(lines[i], ".\n");
        break;
      }

      strcpy(lines[i], sentence);
      numOfLines++;
      //printf("%s", lines[i]); // intial Debug statement
    }

    for (int j = numOfLines-1; j>=0; j--){
      printf("%s\n", lines[j]);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Note that you need to either set a maximum and exit the loop before that max is reached or get the user to enter the maximum and set it dynamically.

Comment: What if there is no known maximum, and the user can just keep entering as much as they possibly want until they decide to exit

Comment: @user6913230 then you can use a data structure/buffer set which grows dynamically as the user enters more data. so turn the loop into a while(true) and then build some sort of linked memory structure where each new element maintains a pointer to its predecessor. this helps with your printing as you only need to follow the list from the start to print everything in the right order.  and set the predecessor in the first element to zero and use that as your terminating condition in your print loop

Comment: The bzero is not a good idea for several reasons: (1) use calloc in the first place instead of repeating the size calculation, (2) on some systems it won't generate null pointers, (3) it's redundant because the later code -- as it should -- ensures that only entries that were assigned a value will then be read.

Answer (score 2):

```
lines[i] = malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(sentence + 1));
```

This is a problem. Should be

```
lines[i] = malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(sentence) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * numOfLines);
> ```

On each iteration, you're allocating a completely new array, and the old one is lost (not freed, and no longer addressable).  What you want here is **realloc**(3).

> ```
>  lines[i] = malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(sentence + 1));
> ```

As [Andrew Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41948595/451601) mentions, you want `strlen(sentence) + 1`.  Your code is allocating 2 fewer bytes than you need.  (Consider what `sentence + 1` is.)  A less error-prone idiom is `1 + strlen(sentence)`.

Posix defines a more convenient function, `strdup`(3), that helps avoid this kind of fencepost error.

One word of advice, if I may:  You're not checking that your allocations return a valid value.  Even though memories are big nowadays (and, on Linux, frequently bigger than actual) correct logic deals with errors from any function call.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix your code, not mentioned yet, is to change:

```
lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * numOfLines);
```

to:

```
lines = realloc(lines, numOfLines * sizeof *lines);
```

(Note, I use the [recommended idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605856/1505939) for `sizeof` to increase code robustness). And have before the loop, `char **lines = NULL;`.

Then the memory block containing the line pointers will be increased in size as necessary.

Note that you should check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc` and take appropriate action if it returned NULL. If you want to be able to recover the program in the case of realloc failure, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986538/how-to-handle-realloc-when-it-fails-due-to-memory).

Comment: So I made the suggested change, however when I run the program and have an input such as:
    a
    b
    c
    d

The output is:
d
c
b
(random characters)  Ignoring the string in index [0], however this only happens when there is greater than 3 lines of input

Comment: @user6913230 you have a bug in your program somewhere