# Understanding Malloc and Realloc in regards to an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, realloc

I have been struggling with the ideas behind malloc and realloc for quite some time now and at the moment I have a problem with dynamically creating an array of structs. I have a `struct triangle` which itself is composed of an array of `struct coordinates`. I would like to be able to have an array of `triangles` which is as large as necessary, but every time I attempt to increase the length of my array, nothing seems to happen. Realloc doesn't fail and neither does malloc. However the new triangles are not inserted in my array. Here is my code for reference.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct triangle {
    struct coordinate point[3];
};
  static size_t size = 0;

static void addTriangle(struct triangle **triangles, struct triangle *t) {
    struct triangle *ts = (struct triangle*) realloc(*triangles, (size+1) * sizeof(struct triangle));
    if(ts == NULL) {
        free(ts);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *triangles = ts;
    triangles[size] = t;
    size++;

}

int main() {
    struct triangle* triangles = (struct triangle *) malloc(sizeof(struct triangle));
    if(triangles == NULL) {
        free(triangles);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        struct coordinate *a = malloc(sizeof(struct coordinate));
        a->x = 1 * i;
        a->y = 2 * i;
        struct coordinate *b = malloc(sizeof(struct coordinate));
        b->x = 3 * i;
        b->y = 4 * i;
        struct coordinate *c = malloc(sizeof(struct coordinate));
        c->x = 5 * i;
        c->y = 6 * i;
        struct triangle *t = malloc(sizeof(struct triangle));
        t->point[0] = *a;
        t->point[1] = *b;
        t->point[2] = *c;

        addTriangle(triangles, t);
    }

}
```

I have tried every variation of this I have found, but I would rather not just blindly throw in & and * until something happens.

Comment: Can you show the definitions of struct coordinate and struct triangle?

Comment: Sure thing, I added them to my code example. sorry about that

Comment: Try sending the address of trangles to the add_traingles function. ie addTrangles( &trangles, t );

Comment: `addTriangle(triangles, t);` Your compiler should complain about different level of indirection for first parameter. You expect a `struct triangle **` but you pass a `struct triangle *`. You should always enable warnings in your compiler. Use -Wall -Wextra

Comment: Not related to your question but you createt memory leaks when allocating memory for coordinates. You could simply use a single variable for that. No pointers needed.

Comment: `triangles[size] = t;` should be `(*triangles)[size] = *t;`.

Comment: If `triangles` is `NULL` after you first call `malloc`, there's no point calling `free` on it as no memory was allocated

Comment: It would be more fun to call `addTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3);`, that definition and usage seems ill-conceived and generally not so helpful.

Comment: There is also a mismatch of what is stored in the array. You store the pointer to the new triangle in the array but you allocate memory for `struct triangle` structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As-is, your program invokes undefined behavior when it passes an uninitialized `*triangles` to `realloc`: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/9ff94de4 . You probably meant to pass `&triangles` when you called it in `main`.

Changing the call in `main` to `addTriangle(&triangles, t);`, the next issue is an out-of-bounds access inside `addTriangle`: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/658228a1 . Again this may be because you have the wrong level of indirection and meant something like `(*triangles)[size]`
 instead of `triangles[size]`.

If I change the line `triangles[size] = t;` to `(*triangles)[size] = *t;` then there is no undefined behavior. You should check whether this program still does what you want, since it was modified: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/8915bd2d

The final version:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct triangle {
    struct coordinate point[3];
};
  static size_t size = 0;

static void addTriangle(struct triangle **triangles, struct triangle *t) {
    struct triangle *ts = (struct triangle*) realloc(*triangles, (size+1) * sizeof(struct triangle));
    if(ts == NULL) {
        free(ts);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *triangles = ts;
    (*triangles)[size] = *t; // a struct assignment
    size++;

}

int main() {
    struct triangle* triangles = (struct triangle *) malloc(sizeof(struct triangle));
    if(triangles == NULL) {
        free(triangles);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        struct coordinate *a = malloc(sizeof(struct coordinate));
        a->x = 1 * i;
        a->y = 2 * i;
        struct coordinate *b = malloc(sizeof(struct coordinate));
        b->x = 3 * i;
        b->y = 4 * i;
        struct coordinate *c = malloc(sizeof(struct coordinate));
        c->x = 5 * i;
        c->y = 6 * i;
        struct triangle *t = malloc(sizeof(struct triangle));
        t->point[0] = *a;
        t->point[1] = *b;
        t->point[2] = *c;

        addTriangle(&triangles, t); /* pass the address of triangles
           so that addTriangle can modify this variable's contents */
    }

}
```

---

### Side remarks not directly related to the problem you asked about

1. As long as you program in C, please [do not cast the result of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/139746) `malloc`. Simply write `struct triangle* triangles = malloc(...`.
2. As noted by @aschepler in the comments, this program still leaks the memory blocks allocated from `main`. These can be freed at the end of each iteration without adding any undefined behavior: https://taas.trust-in-soft.com/tsnippet/t/a0705262 . Doing this, you may realize that `t->point[0] = *a;`, ... are in fact struct assignments and that it was unnecessary to allocate a separate `struct coordinate` in the first place: you could just fill in each `struct coordinate` member of the `struct triangle`. In addition, it was unnecessary to allocate the `struct triangle` in `main`, too: you could just use a local variable for that, since anyway the contents of the struct will be copied by the function `addTriangle` to the array that `main`'s local variable `triangles` points to.
3. Also you don't need to call `free(triangles)` if `triangles` is a null pointer in `main`:

   ```
   struct triangle* triangles = (struct triangle *) malloc(...
   if(triangles == NULL) {
       free(triangles);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   ```

   It is allowed to pass a null pointer to `free`, and this does what you would expect (it does nothing), but since you know that `triangles` is `NULL` in the `then` branch, simply call `exit`.
4. Handling the failure of `realloc` [on the other hand is a subtle subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986538/139746). Your program is doing it wrong, but it does not really matter because it calls `exit` immediately.
5. Storing information about the allocated array pointed by `main`'s local variable `triangles` in a static file-scope variable `size` is not consistent. The two are so closely related that they should be in the same scope. Since you need `addTriangle` to be able to change `size`, you cannot simply move `size` to be a local variable of `main`, but you can move the local variable `triangles` of `main` to file scope, next to `size`. If you prefer to make `size` a local variable of `main` after all, you will need to pass its address to the function `addTriangle` so that the latter can update the former.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes, I will change it.

Comment: You should include the modified source in the answer with explanation why you changed it and it should be acceptable.

Comment: Another possible improvement: it's not necessary to `malloc` the `struct coordinate` objects (which are currently leaked).  Just `struct coordinate a = { 1*i, 2*i }; t->point[0] = a;` etc.

Comment: @aschepler This is a good suggestion but is not strictly related to the problem the OP was facing, so I'm torn about including it.

Comment: This does indeed seem to work. If I may ask, what is happening with the address when you give &triangles in main and then expect **triangles in addTriangle? You're giving the address of the pointer of triangles and in realloc using the pointer of the pointer of triangles? It seems redundant, but thats why I'm here in the first place

Comment: @user25758 What you seem to want to do is to allow `addTriangle` to extend the array pointed to by the variable named `triangles` in `main`. In order to do that, it may be necessary to move the whole array somewhere else, so the function `addTriangle`, if it is intended to work this way, needs to be able to modify `main`'s variable `triangle`. In order to be able to do that, it must receive that variable's address. You had mostly the right levels of indirection everywhere else, so I fixed the program in order to be consistent.

Comment: @aschepler See I started pointing out things that were not the initial question and look at my answer now! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the whole body of your `for` loop with

```
struct triangle t = {{{i, 2*i},{3*i,4*i},{5*i,6*i}}};
addTriangle(&triangles, &t);
```

Please note the `&` before the parameters, because you want to pass the address of both.

I already noticed as a comment that `triangles[size] = t;` should be `(*triangles)[size] = *t;`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct triangle {
    struct coordinate point[3];
};
  static size_t size = 0;

static void addTriangle(struct triangle **triangles, struct triangle *t) {
    struct triangle *ts = realloc(*triangles, (size+1) * sizeof(struct triangle));
    if(ts == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *triangles = ts;
    (*triangles)[size] = *t;
    size++;

}

int main() {
    struct triangle* triangles = malloc(sizeof(struct triangle));
    if(triangles == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        struct triangle t = {{{i, 2*i},{3*i,4*i},{5*i,6*i}}};
        addTriangle(&triangles, &t);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d %d, %d %d, %d %d\n", triangles[i].point[0].x,
                                        triangles[i].point[0].y,
                                        triangles[i].point[1].x,
                                        triangles[i].point[1].y,
                                        triangles[i].point[2].x,
                                        triangles[i].point[2].y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function call as

```
addTriangle(&triangles, t);
```