# How to fix infinite printing of random number?

Tags: c, loops, printf, command-line-interface, scanf

I wrote a program that scans an unknown amount of integers into an array but when I run it, it print the last value it has gotten an infinite amount of times.

For example for the input: 1 2 3 4 5

The output would be 55555555555555555555555...

Why does this happen and how can I fix that?

My goal here is to create a array, for an instance {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and then print what it scanned into the array, ONLY ONCE...

```
int *pSet = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)); int i; int c;
printf("Please enter a stream of numbers to make a set out of them: ");
printf("\n");

scanf("%d", &c);
pSet[0] = c;
printf("%d ", c);
for(i = 1; c != EOF; i++) {
    pSet = (int*) realloc(pSet, sizeof(int)*(i+1));
    if(pSet == NULL) {
        return FAIL;        
    }
    scanf("%d", &c);
    pSet[i] = c;
    printf("%d ", c);
}

free(pSet);
```

Comment: You never check if `scanf()` actually works.

Comment: I tried to fix my input according to what you sent but it doesn't change anything. I sent to the program: 1 2 3 4 5 (Enter) (Enter) @BurnsBA

Comment: If scanf() didn't work the variable c wouldn't have been initialized. The program print c, and at the time of printing c is 5. I hardly think this is the issue... But thanks anyways! @AndrewHenle

Comment: A problem in this few a lines of mostly self-contained code is *born* to be single-stepped in a *debugger*. And stop ignoring the results of those `scanf` calls, lest you violate [Spencer's Sixth Commandment](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html). Finally, I challenge you to point out where, in the [documentation for `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), it states it populates integer-formatted output arguments with `EOF` once the stream hits said-same (because no such behavior exists). Short version: *Read and understand the requirements of the functions you're using*.

Comment: Unnecessary "[not solved]" title edit removed.  Solved or not solved, the title need not change.

Comment: How do you want to indicate that you are done inputting numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this happen (?) (print ... an infinite amount of times.)

Look at the loop terminating conditions `c != EOF`.

```
int c;
scanf("%d", &c);
for(i = 1; c != EOF; i++) {  // Not good code
  scanf("%d", &c);
}
```

`EOF` is some negative value, often -1.  `scanf("%d", &c)` attempts to read user input and convert to an `int`.  `scanf()` returns a `1`,`0`,`EOF` depending on if it 1) succeeded, 2) failed to find numeric text or 3) end-of-file or input error occurred.  Unfortunately code does not use that return value.  Instead code used the number read, `c` and checked if that number read was the same as `EOF`.

---

> how can I fix that?

Only loop when the return value of `scanf()` is as expected (1).

```
for(i = 1; scanf("%d", &c) == 1; i++) {
  ...
}
```

---

Putting this together with some other ideas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Please enter a stream of numbers to make a set out of them:\n");
  int *pSet = NULL;  // Start with no allocation
  size_t i = 0;

  int c;
  for (i = 0; scanf("%d", &c) == 1; i++) {
    //        +---------------------------  No cast needed.
    //        v               v----------v  Use sizeof de-referenced pointer
    void *p =   realloc(pSet, sizeof *pSet * (i + 1));
    if (p == NULL) {
      free(pSet);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    pSet = p;
    pSet[i] = c;
  }

  for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    printf("%d ", pSet[j]);
  }

  free(pSet);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the input 1 2 3 4 5, The output was: 1 0 2 130017 3 130009 4 130001 5 129993 @chux

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad Code amended - remove extra `++`

Answer (score 1):

You should stop your loop when scanf fails. According to the **manual**:

> On  success,  [scanf] **return[s]** the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer  than  provided  for,  or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.
>   The  value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs. [...]

So you can turn your for loop into a while one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FAIL 0
int main() {
  int *pSet = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  int c;
  int i=0;
  printf("Please enter a stream of numbers to make a set out of them: ");
  while(scanf("%d", &c) == 1) {
    pSet[i] = c;
    pSetNew = (int*) realloc(pSet, sizeof(int)*(i+1));
    if(pSetNew == NULL) {
      free(pSet);
      return FAIL;        
    } else {
      pSet = pSetNew;
    }
    printf("%d ", c);
    i++;
  }

  free(pSet);
}
```

But if you want a more robust piece of code, I suggest you to retrieve the answer as a string (`NULL`-terminated array of `char`), and then parse it with dedicated functions like `strtol` which let you check if the *whole* string is a valid entry, and not only the first characters.

*Note: HengLi fixed a potential memory leak in the code sample above*

Comment: *** Error in `./catch': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x088c8008 ***  @Amessihel

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad It should be better to search for existing answer related to this issue, or asking a new question describing accurately your environment, to avoid to create a duplicate.

Comment: There is potentially a memory leak problem in the code. When realloc cannot find enough space to allocate, it returns a NULL and keeps the original space allocated. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986538/how-to-handle-realloc-when-it-fails-due-to-memory/1986572#1986572) shows how to fix the problem by using a new variable to hold the return of realloc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems.

1) Terminate the loop when `scanf` fails instead of using EOF. Do that by checking that the return value is 1 (i.e. the number of input items
       successfully matched)

2) Don't allocate memory until it's needed

3) **Never** do `realloc` directly into the target pointer - always use a temp variable.

Fixing this your code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *pSet = NULL;
    printf("Please enter a stream of numbers to make a set out of them: ");
    printf("\n");

    int i = 0;
    int c;
    while (1) {
         if (scanf("%d", &c) != 1)
         {
             printf("Terminating input loop\n");
             break;
         }

         int* tmp = realloc(pSet, sizeof(int)*(i+1));
         if(tmp == NULL) {
            printf("oh dear...\n");
            break;
         }
         pSet = tmp;
         pSet[i++] = c;
         printf("%d ", c);
    }

    for (int j=0; j < i; ++j) printf("%d\n", pSet[j]);
    free(pSet);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 stop
```

Output:

```
Please enter a stream of numbers to make a set out of them: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
Terminating input loop
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: realloc in temp (line 17) fails everytime. @4386427

Comment: https://ideone.com/XR4tQt I changed your code, some of the things you wrote are not according to the C syntax. @4386427

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad What did you find specifically that was not "not according to the C syntax"?  What current version of C are you using?  I suspect it is a 20 years old version.  This answer is valid C.

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad " not according to the C syntax" What? Please clarify

Comment: I sent the code after fixing it. For example, in C the compiler won't let you define and initialize all at once inside a loop, as you did with the array tmp. @4386427

Comment: Besides, realloc fails everytime. For any input the output would be :         
Please enter a stream of numbers to make a set out of them: 
oh dear...
Segmentation fault (core dumped) @4386427

Comment: @ShadowOverLoad You must be using some very old C compiler. And if the `realloc` fails your system is not only old but also buggy. Once again - see here https://ideone.com/HSKTCH