# C: How to store pointers to structs in a dynamic array within another struct?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-arrays

My idea is to have a struct `Person` which holds the data for a person and a struct `Family` which contains the number of family members and an array with pointers to the persons. The persons shall be dynamically collected at runtime, stored on the heap, and the `Family` struct shall contain an array of pointers to these persons (`members`).
Now I have some troubles with this dynamic array and wonder how to properly allocate memory and add these pointers to the array.

This is my current code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

typedef struct Person{
    int age;
    char first_name[256];
    char last_name[256];
} Person;

typedef struct {
    size_t number_members;
    Person **members;
} Family;

void init_person(Person *p);
void add_person_to_family(Family *f, Person *p);
void print_person(Person *p);

int main() {
    size_t number_members = 2;
    Family *f = calloc(1, sizeof(Family));

    for (int i = 0; i < number_members; ++i) {
        Person *p = calloc(1, sizeof(Person));
        init_person(p);
        add_person_to_family(f, p);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < f->number_members; ++i) {
        print_person(*f[i].members);
    }
    return 0;
}

void init_person(Person *p)
{
    printf("Enter first name: \n");
    scanf("%s", p->first_name);
    printf("Enter last name: \n");
    scanf("%s", p->last_name);
    printf("Enter age: \n");
    scanf("%i", &p->age);
}

void add_person_to_family(Family *f, Person *p)
{
    f->number_members++;
    f = realloc(f, sizeof(size_t) + (f->number_members) * sizeof(Person *));
    f->members = realloc(f->members, (f->number_members) * sizeof(Person *));
    f->members = p;
}

void print_person(Person *p)
{
    printf("Age: %d\n", p->age);
    printf("First Name: %s\n", p->first_name);
    printf("Last Name: %s\n", p->last_name);
}
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of "I have some troubles with this dynamic array"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = realloc(f, sizeof(size_t) + (f->number_members) * sizeof(Person *));
```

The line above makes no sense whatsoever and needs to be just deleted. A `Family` is a single struct, its size never changes, whether or not some of its fields point to arrays. It contains a `size_t` field and a pointer field. Sizes of both are constant. You never need to `realloc` it. By the way, the size of a `struct` is not the sum of sizes of its fields.

```
f->members = p;
```

The line above is an error. `f->members` points into an array of pointers to `Person`. You want to update an element of that array. An array element is normally accessed with the `[]` operator. The line should be

```
f->members[i] = p;
```

Determining what `i` should be is left as an exercise.

```
*f[i].members
```

This is also an error. `f` is not an array and does not point to an array element, so `f[i]` is not what you want. It is a pointer to a single `struct`. Fields of a single struct are accessed with the `->` operator. `members` is the one that should be indexed. You need

```
f->members[i]
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9P5b5KGh9)

There are other problems, like [unsafe use of `scanf`](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) and [not checking return values of library functions](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/15692/ignoring-return-values-of-library-functions) including, but not limited to, [realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986538/how-to-handle-realloc-when-it-fails-due-to-memory).

Comment: Thank you so much. This was so incredibly helpful; also regarding your remarks at the end.