# re-initializing an array of nodes with calloc()

Tags: c

I am writing a maze game and have come across some issues when running it through valgrind. The code below is a simplified version to demonstrate the basic structure of my game.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init(void);
int play(void);

typedef struct Node {
    int x, y;
} Node;

/* global variables */
Node *nodes;
int width, height;

int main(void)
{
    width = height = 10; /* initial game maze dimensions */
    do {
        init();
    } while (play());

    free(nodes);
    nodes = NULL;

    return 0;
}

void init(void)
{
    nodes = calloc((size_t)(width * height), sizeof(Node));
    if (nodes == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }
}

int play(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != 'q') {
        if (c == 'n') {
            width = height = 15; /* new game maze dimensions */
            printf("new game\n");
#if 0
            free(nodes);
            nodes = NULL;
#endif
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run with 'valgrind -s --leak-check=full ./free' and then enter 'n' (for new game), followed by 'q' (to quit).

With the #if 0/#endif block in play(), valgrind returns "LEAK SUMMARY: definitely lost: 800 bytes in 1 blocks".

With #if 1/#endif, valgrind returns no leaks but in my actual game, valgrind gives errors like "Invalid read size of 1" and "Address 0x4c49865 is 7,765 bytes inside a block of size 58,144 free'd".

After searching here on stackoverflow, I learned I am seeing these errors because I am calling calloc() twice for 'nodes' and/or using calloc() after free().  I have tried experimenting with an 'if' loop to initialize only once and also attempted to use realloc(), but I run into other problems, like 'nodes' isn't the correct size or it retains the data from the initial game.

My question is this: Is there a correct way to re-initialize and clear 'nodes' using the new game maze dimensions?  Also, when and where should I be using free(nodes)?

Comment: If I switch `#if 0` to `#if 1` it runs clean for me under valgrind.  Are you sure that's the code that gives you the "invalid read" error?

Comment: @dbush, yes, the example here runs clean under valgrind, but in my actual game, this block of code triggers the valgrind errors.  i tried to simplify the problem here in my example, assuming i've just done something wrong with the way i'm trying to re-initialize the maze when 'new game' is selected.  if this example is correct, then i will have to troubleshoot my actual game code some more

Comment: Don't simplify it so much that the problem goes away. We need an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Some side issues: `(size_t)(width * height)` better as `(size_t)width * height` to less likely overflow.  `Node *nodes;` --> `Node *nodes = NULL;` as `NULL` is not certainly a zero pattern.  `while ((c = getchar()) != 'q') {` risks an infinite loop.  Better as `while ((c = getchar()) != 'q' && c != EOF) {`.

Comment: You probably overwrite `nodes` at some place. Make sure to keep allocation and freeing together to avoid such problems. You might want to add debugging outputs at each allocation and freeing. -- You can even use your own journaling version of `calloc()` and `free()` to investigate this further. But at the end of the day, Valgrind is doing quite exactly that.

Comment: The first line in `init` could simply be `free(nodes);` Or change the loop `do {
        init();
    } while (play());` to `int p = 1; while(p) { init(); p = play(); free(nodes); }` Then you will only have a single place calling `free`

Comment: @the-busybee i'm trying to reuse nodes when i select a new game, so yes, it's likely being overwritten (i can specifically trigger valgrind when i do a new game and then move my player one square).  i believe i'm seeing a similar situation as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435433/what-happens-if-i-use-malloc-twice-on-the-same-pointer-c, ie, it's a memory leak because i'm calling calloc() twice.  i tried realloc() with memset(), but it doesn't work at all (i don't think i understand realloc(), tbh).  what i'd like is nodes in the new size and fully zero'd when i select new game.

Comment: i think figured it out - i used a 'static Node *' variable in my move player function.  removing it and using free(nodes); nodes = NULL; after a new game is selected now satisfies valgrind.  @chux, thanks for the tips, i deployed some of them.  i am still curious, though, if this is the proper way to reuse & clear the nodes array (i'm hung up on the using malloc() twice on the same pointer quesion)

Comment: @rsarson A good way to use dynamic data is `some_type *ptr = NULL or malloc/calloc(...);`  later `free(ptr); ptr = NULL or malloc/calloc(...);` (repeat as needed), finally `free(ptr); ptr = NULL;`.  Note that it is OK to call `free(ptr);` even if `ptr == NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easy --- and safe --- way to go is to write the code around your data and encapsulate `Maze` as you could do in any more object-oriented languages.

**Below is a complete example, with comments and output, of an alternative way of writing this kind of code.**

### from the original code

```
void init(void);
int  play(void);

typedef struct Node
{
    int x, y;
} Node;

/* global variables */
Node* nodes;
int   width, height;
```

In data structures in general when you see a `Node` thing there is some *object* around it, an array, a linked list, a map, a set, whathever.

But the node is not the structure and the structure is not a node. **A structure is a (possibly empty) collection of nodes. And the nodes points to --- or contains --- data**, a unit of data per node.

In your case the structure is a `Maze`, an array of `Nodes`. The data is a pair of `int`.

But **you have no `struct` for a `Maze`**. Failure on doing so takes your representation far from the model itself. This will make the code hard to implement, to test and to change.

You have a single pointer `Node*`, a global one, and 2 global `int`. This is fragile. And `play` relies on a single global pointer and returns nothing: more and more problems.

#### An alternative: `Maze` as an *object*

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned width;
    unsigned height;
    Node*    nd;
} Maze;
```

This is just an example, and I will left an implementation around this, in order to illustrate the way many people write these things

#### some operations on `Maze`

```
Maze* so_create(unsigned W, unsigned H);
Maze* so_destroy(Maze* maze);
int   so_display(Maze* maze, const char* title);
Node* so_get_node(unsigned x, unsigned y, Maze* maze);
Maze* so_resize(
    Maze** original, unsigned new_w, unsigned new_h);
// shows a single node
int so_show_node(Node* node, const char* msg);
// helper: just number all maze nodes
int so_fill_maze(Maze* maze);
int so_play(Maze* maze); // does nothing here
```

This way `play()` could be `int so_play(Maze* maze)` and you can see one of the  differences: it becomes easy to play dozens of mazes on the same code.

A very simple implementation for these functions are below. They are minimal, with 5 to 10 lines each, and serves only as illustration.

- `so_create(w,h)` returns a new `Maze` with the required size
- `so_destroy()` returns `NULL`and destroys the maze, deallocating the memory
- `so_display()` shows a maze on screen so the program can test itself. And a message can be inserted so we will not need to insert dozens of calls to `printf()`
- `so_get_node` returns a new `Node` with the values of the one in the specified position in the `Maze`, or `NULL`
- `so_resize()` does the obvious, but here it copies nodes were possible, just for fun and testing
- `so_show_node` prints a single node. This is to make life easier if we want to customize the way each node is printed. The version in the example here uses the format `(xxx,yyy)`
- `so_fill_maze` load each `Node` in `Maze` with its position, so we can see on screen how things are going.
- `so_play` does nothing and it is just as the alternative to `void  play(void)`

#### `main` for a test run

This code is self-explanatory but:

- a 2x4 maze is created
- it is displayed we expect all nodes `(0,0)`
- `fill_maze` is called, numbering all nodes with its position
- the `Maze` is displayed again
- the maze is resized  and displayed again
- a node at a certain position is consulted
- the data is `free`d

```
#include "stuff.h"

int main(void)
{
  Maze* tst = so_create(2, 4);
  so_display(tst, "2x4 just created");
  so_fill_maze(tst);
  so_display(tst, "\nsame one, after fill");

  // tst is destroyed inside so_resize()
  Maze* new_m = so_resize(&tst, 5, 5); 
  so_display(new_m, "\nresize from maze above");

  so_play(new_m);

  Node* node = so_get_node(1,3, new_m);
  so_show_node(node, "node at (1,3) is ");
  free(node);
  new_m = so_destroy(new_m);  // free last
  return 0;
}
```

#### output for this test

```
2x4 just created    [2,4] Maze

(  0,  0) (  0,  0)
(  0,  0) (  0,  0)
(  0,  0) (  0,  0)
(  0,  0) (  0,  0)

same one, after fill    [2,4] Maze

(  0,  0) (  1,  0)
(  0,  1) (  1,  1)
(  0,  2) (  1,  2)
(  0,  3) (  1,  3)

resize from maze above    [5,5] Maze

(  0,  0) (  1,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0)
(  0,  1) (  1,  1) (  0,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0)
(  0,  2) (  1,  2) (  0,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0)
(  0,  3) (  1,  3) (  0,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0)
(  0,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0) (  0,  0)
play(5,5)
node at (1,3) is (  1,  3)
```

### The code for the example

#### a header file `stuff.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned width;
    unsigned height;
    Node*    nd;
} Maze;

Maze* so_create(unsigned W, unsigned H);
Maze* so_destroy(Maze* maze);
int   so_display(Maze* maze, const char* title);
Node* so_get_node(unsigned y, unsigned x, Maze* maze);
Maze* so_resize(
    Maze** original, unsigned new_w, unsigned new_h);
// shows a single node
int so_show_node(Node* node, const char* msg);
// helper: just number all maze nodes
int so_fill_maze(Maze* maze);
int so_play(Maze* maze); // does nothing here
```

#### the functions in `stuff.c`

```
#include "stuff.h"

Maze* so_create(unsigned W, unsigned H)
{
    Maze* one = (Maze*)malloc(sizeof(Maze));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    one->width  = W;
    one->height = H;
    size_t size = (size_t)W * (size_t)(H) * sizeof(Node);
    one->nd     = (Node*)malloc(size);
    if (one->nd == NULL)
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(one->nd, 0, size);  // clear nodes
    return one;
}

Maze* so_destroy(Maze* one)
{
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    free(one->nd);
    free(one);
    return NULL;
}

int so_display(Maze* maze, const char* msg)
{
    if (maze == NULL) return -1;
    // an optional message can be useful
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf(
        "    [%u,%u] Maze\n\n", maze->width, maze->height);
    Node* p = maze->nd;
    for (unsigned h = 0; h < maze->height; h += 1)
    {
        for (unsigned w = 0; w < maze->width; w += 1)
            so_show_node(p++, NULL);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

Node* so_get_node(unsigned x, unsigned y, Maze* maze)
{
    if (maze == NULL) return NULL;
    if (maze->width < x) return NULL;
    if (maze->height < y) return NULL;
    // ok, we have maze and point (x,y) is ok
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (node == NULL) return NULL;
    *node = *(maze->nd + y * maze->width + x);
    return node;
}

Maze* so_resize(
    Maze** original, unsigned new_w, unsigned new_h)
{   // original is Maze** so we can reset the pointer
    // here
    Maze* one = so_create(new_w, new_h);
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    unsigned lim_w =
        new_w < (*original)->width ? new_w : (*original)->width;
    unsigned lim_h =
        new_h < (*original)->height ? new_h : (*original)->height;
    Node* p_new = one->nd;
    Node* p_old = (*original)->nd;
    // copy nodes to new maze were possible
    for (unsigned h = 0; h < lim_h; h += 1)
        for (unsigned w = 0; w < lim_w; w += 1)
            *(one->nd + h * one->width + w) =
                *((*original)->nd + h * (*original)->width + w);
    *original = so_destroy(*original);
    return one;
}

int so_show_node(Node* node, const char* msg)
{
    if (node == NULL) return -1;
    // an optional message can be useful also here
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("(%3d,%3d) ", node->x, node->y);
    return 0;
}

int so_fill_maze(Maze* maze)
{  // each node will have (x,y) = the node position
    // in maze, just for testing
    if (maze == NULL) return -1;  // no maze
    Node* p = maze->nd;
    for (unsigned h = 0; h < maze->height; h += 1)
        for (unsigned w = 0; w < maze->width; w += 1)
            p->x = w, p->y = h, p++;
    return 0;
}

int so_play(Maze* maze)
{
    if (maze == NULL) return -1;
    printf("play(%u,%u)\n", maze->width, maze->height);
    return 0;
}
```

`main` is just above in the comments.

HIH

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed that you end up calling calloc multiple times in a loop and if you don't `free(nodes)` in between, then that's a memory leak.

> My question is this: Is there a correct way to re-initialize and clear 'nodes' using the new game maze dimensions? Also, when and where should I be using free(nodes)?

Since you allocated the whole thing in a single `calloc` call, you essentially have a "flat" 2D array with everything allocated in adjacent cells.

The easiest fix would be move `calloc` before the loop, move `free` after the loop and reset the data using `memset(nodes, 0, width * height * sizeof(Node))`.

*However*, why are you using dynamic allocation in the first place? The dimensions are known at compile-time. Something like this would be faster and less error prone all at once:

```c
#define width 10
#define height 10

int main(void)
{
  static Node nodes[width][height];
  ...
```

`static` to avoid having the array allocated on the stack.